# Firebase returning data with $value, $id and $priority AngularJs

Tags: html, angularjs, json, firebase

I am trying to get data from Firebase in my HTML with AngularJS. It is working fine, but as I reach the child node it is showing data in unexpected form.
Please find the images for details:

Json File that I have Imported on Firebase:

> [image: My Json File]

FireBase Data Representation:

> [image: FireBase Data]

Data Returned in HTML:

> [image]

Expected Data as

> [image]

In my controller I am trying to get data from FireBase as:

```
$scope.locService = $rootScope.service;
  var serviceRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL+"ABC/location/"+$rootScope.location+"/services/"+$rootScope.service+"/"+$rootScope.serviceDetail+"");
  $scope.details = $firebaseArray(serviceRef);
```

the $rootScope values are coming correctly as it is returning data(which is not in the expected format, ie with $id, $value, $priority).

In my HTML:

```
<div class="content has-header">
      <h2>{{details[0]}}</h2>
</div>
```

Please help me out. Thanks in advance for your suggestions

Comment: Those unexpected attributes are described in the documentation. So they're expected, in fact: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/synchronized-arrays.html

Answer (score 0):

AngularFire creates a synchronized array from a series of Firebase DataSnapshots. The Snapshot contains the data as well as other useful data such as the `key` and `priority`. AngularFire uses the `$` prefix to include this data for each item in the array.

In your case you're trying to synchronize a series of primitives, in order for AngularFire to give you important info like the `key`, it includes the primitive in an object, and gives you access to the primitive value via the `$value` property.

[**Check out the AngularFire docs on meta fields for more information.**](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/synchronized-arrays.html#section-meta-fields)

If you don't want this behavior, then you'll need to either use `$firebaseObject()` or go one level up in the JSON tree.

In your case you likely want to use a `$firebaseObject()`.

```
$scope.locService = $rootScope.service;
var serviceRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL+"ABC/location/"+$rootScope.location+"/services/"+$rootScope.service+"/"+$rootScope.serviceDetail+"");
$scope.details = $firebaseObject(serviceRef);
```